# Detecting focus event on algolia autocomplete field

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, algolia

I have an input for algolia autocomplete in my template:

```
     <form action="/search" method="get">
       <div class="input-group">
         <span class="input-group-addon">
           <button type="submit" class="search-button">
             <i class="ion-ios-search-strong"></i>
           </button>
         </span>
         <input type="text" name="q" class="search-input search-input-small-js form-control aa-input-search" placeholder="Search for players and videos ..." aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
       </div>
     </form>
```

This the css for it:

```
.algolia-autocomplete {
  display: flex!important;
  flex: auto!important;
}
.aa-dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  top: -6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 6px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: $white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.aa-dropdown-menu:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 0;
  top: -7px;
  border-top: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  border-right: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  border-radius: 2px;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  left: 24px;
}

.aa-dropdown-menu .aa-suggestions {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.aa-dropdown-menu [class^="aa-dataset-"] {
  position: relative;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px;
  color: #3c3e42;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.aa-dropdown-menu * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.aa-suggestion {
  padding: 0 4px 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 38px;
  clear: both;
}
.aa-suggestion span {
  white-space: nowrap !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
}
.aa-suggestion.aa-cursor {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.aa-suggestion em {
  color: #00bcd4;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.aa-suggestion img {
  float: left;
  height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.aa-suggestion a {
  color: #3c3e42;
}

.aa-suggestions-category {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #3c3e42;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(102, 105, 105, 0.17);
}

.powered-by-algolia {
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(102, 105, 105, 0.17);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30px;
}

.aa-input-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative; }
.aa-input-search {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 12px 28px 12px 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none; }
.aa-input-search::-webkit-search-decoration, .aa-input-search::-webkit-search-cancel-button, .aa-input-search::-webkit-search-results-button, .aa-input-search::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
  display: none;
}
.media {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.media-body {
  p {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

And this is my js file:

```
var client = algoliasearch('myKey', 'myValue');
var players = client.initIndex('players');
var videos = client.initIndex('videos');

var timeAgo = function(selector) {

    var templates = {
        prefix: "",
        suffix: " ago",
        seconds: "less than a minute",
        minute: "about a minute",
        minutes: "%d minutes",
        hour: "about an hour",
        hours: "about %d hours",
        day: "a day",
        days: "%d days",
        month: "about a month",
        months: "%d months",
        year: "about a year",
        years: "%d years"
    };
    var template = function (t, n) {
        return templates[t] && templates[t].replace(/%d/i, Math.abs(Math.round(n)));
    };

    var timer = function (time) {
        if (!time) return;
        time = time.replace(/\.\d+/, ""); // remove milliseconds
        time = time.replace(/-/, "/").replace(/-/, "/");
        time = time.replace(/T/, " ").replace(/Z/, " UTC");
        time = time.replace(/([\+\-]\d\d)\:?(\d\d)/, " $1$2"); // -04:00 -> -0400
        time = new Date(time * 1000 || time);

        var now = new Date();
        var seconds = ((now.getTime() - time) * .001) >> 0;
        var minutes = seconds / 60;
        var hours = minutes / 60;
        var days = hours / 24;
        var years = days / 365;

        return templates.prefix + (
        seconds < 45 && template('seconds', seconds) || seconds < 90 && template('minute', 1) || minutes < 45 && template('minutes', minutes) || minutes < 90 && template('hour', 1) || hours < 24 && template('hours', hours) || hours < 42 && template('day', 1) || days < 30 && template('days', days) || days < 45 && template('month', 1) || days < 365 && template('months', days / 30) || years < 1.5 && template('year', 1) || template('years', years)) + templates.suffix;
    };

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('timeago');
    for (var i in elements) {
        var $this = elements[i];
        if (typeof $this === 'object') {
            $this.innerHTML = timer($this.getAttribute('title') || $this.getAttribute('datetime'));
        }
    }
    // update time every minute
    setTimeout(timeAgo, 60000);
};

autocomplete('.search-input', {
    templates: {
        footer: '<div class="powered-by-algolia"><div class="pull-right"><img src="/imagecache/xs/Algolia_logo_bg-white.jpg" /></div></div>'
      }
    },
    [{
      source: autocomplete.sources.hits(players, { hitsPerPage: 5 }),
      displayKey: 'first_name',
      templates: {
        header: '<div class="aa-suggestions-category"><span>Players</span></div>',
        suggestion: function(suggestion) {
          var birthday = suggestion.birthday;
          var birthdayArray = birthday.split('/');
          var age = function (birthDay, birthMonth, birthYear) {
            var todayDate = new Date();
            var todayYear = todayDate.getFullYear();
            var todayMonth = todayDate.getMonth();
            var todayDay = todayDate.getDate();
            var age = todayYear - birthYear;

            if (todayMonth < birthMonth - 1){
              age--;
            }

            if (birthMonth - 1 == todayMonth && todayDay < birthDay){
              age--;
            }

            return age;
          }

          var old = age(birthdayArray[0], birthdayArray[1], birthdayArray[2]);

          return '<span>'
                + '<a href="/player/' + suggestion.id + '/' + suggestion.first_name.toLowerCase() + '-' + suggestion.last_name.toLowerCase() + '">'
                +   '<div class="media">'
                +     '<div class="media-left">'
                +       '<img class="media-object" src="/imagecache/small/' + suggestion.image_filename + '">'
                +     '</div>'
                +     '<div class="media-body">'
                +       '<p>' + suggestion._highlightResult.first_name.value + " " + suggestion._highlightResult.last_name.value + '<small> ' + old + ' years</small>' + '</p>'
                +       '<small> ' + suggestion.nationality + ' '+ suggestion.position + '</small>'
                +     '</div>'
                +   '</div>'
                + '</a>'
                +'</span>';
        }
      }
    },
    {
      source: autocomplete.sources.hits(videos, { hitsPerPage: 5 }),
      displayKey: 'title',
      templates: {
        header: '<div class="aa-suggestions-category"><span>Videos</span></div>',
        suggestion: function(suggestion) {
          timeAgo();
          return '<span>'
                +  '<a href="/player/video/' + suggestion.uid + '/' + suggestion.player_name.toLowerCase() + '-' + suggestion.player_surname.toLowerCase() + '">'
                +    '<div class="media">'
                +      '<img class="d-flex mr-3" src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/videos.football-talents.com/' + suggestion.video_id + '_1.jpg">'
                +      '<div class="media-body">'
                +        '<p>' + suggestion._highlightResult.title.value + ' <small class="timeago" title="' + suggestion.created_at + '">' + suggestion.created_at + '</small>' + '</p>'
                +        '<small> ' + suggestion._highlightResult.player_name.value + " " + suggestion._highlightResult.player_surname.value + '</small>'
                +      '</div>'
                +    '</div>'
                +  '</a>'
                +'</span>';
        }
      }
    }
]).on('autocomplete:updated', function(event, suggestion, dataset) {
  var timeagoTimeout;
  clearTimeout(timeagoTimeout);
  timeAgo();
  timeagoTimeout = setTimeout(timeAgo, 60000);
});
```

I was trying in various ways to detect a focus event on that input field, but nothing worked, this was one of the attempts:

```
var input = document.getElementsByClassName('search-input-small-js')[0];

  function inputFocused() {
      if ($('body').hasClass('pml-open')) {
          $('body').removeClass('pml-open');
          $('html, body').css('overflowY', 'auto');
      }
  }

  input.addEventListener('focusin', inputFocused);
```

How can I detect focus event on the algolia autocomplete, I have tried to find some events for that case in their api documentation, but couldn't find anything specifically for this. Not sure how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using vanilla JavaScript you simply get the DOM node and attach an event listener for 'focusin' to the element. You've done this and it seems to work just fine.

I initially used your own code without the Algolia library which worked fine. In response to your comment I've updated the answer to use Algolia, building on top of the official example provided by the Algolia documentation. This also works exactly as expected. You should post a working example as a snippet onto your question to make it easier for people to analyse.

I can categorically say your issue is not a focus problem.

I would wager that the below line in your inputFocused function isn't evaluating to true. Perhaps try setting a break-point within inputHandler function and inspect the DOM when it hits to see if if the body element has the 'pml-open' class.

As a side note, are you sure it's '**pml-open**' and not '**pnl-open**'?

```
if($('body').hasClass('pml-open'))
```

Alternatively assign the result of the above line to a variable and log the value in your inputFocused function.

E.g.

```
var pmlOpen = $('body').hasClass('pml-open');
console.log('pmlOpen is: ' + pmlOpen);
if(pmlOpen) {//...
```

The below snippet is using the code from the Autocomplete tutorial (The defacto credible source for Algolia) located at https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/search-ui/autocomplete/auto-complete/

I can confirm the input is firing the focusin event when it receives focus and you can see this for your self by running the snippet.

Your problem is almost certainly not a focus issue. The below snippet is working on Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Internet Explorer 11. I don't have access to Safari to test it on.

```js
var client = algoliasearch("Q71HM8430Y", "7f42b7cbd41474bf777414c24302d4a4"),
  index = client.initIndex("players");
autocomplete("#aa-demo-1-input", {
  hint: !1,
  debug: !0
}, {
  source: autocomplete.sources.hits(index, {
    hitsPerPage: 5
  }),
  displayKey: "name",
  templates: {
    suggestion: function(e) {
      return "<span>" + e._highlightResult.name.value + "</span><span>" + e._highlightResult.team.value + "</span>"
    }
  }
});

var input = document.querySelector('#aa-demo-1-input');

input.addEventListener('focusin', inputFocused);

function inputFocused() {
  console.log('input received focus');
}
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700";
.aa-demo-1 {
  height: 310px;
  text-align: center
}

.aa-input-container p {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important
}

.aa-demo-1 .aa-input-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative
}

.aa-demo-1 .aa-input-container input[type=search] {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(241, 241, 241, 0.35) !important;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(241, 241, 241, 0.35) !important
}

.aa-demo-1 .algolia-autocomplete {
  top: 0 !important
}

.aa-demo-1 .aa-input-search {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 12px 28px 12px 12px;
  border: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: .2s;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(241, 241, 241, 0.35);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(241, 241, 241, 0.35);
  font-size: 11px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #333;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none
}

.aa-demo-1 .aa-input-search::-webkit-search-decoration,
.aa-demo-1 .aa-input-search::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
.aa-demo-1 .aa-input-search::-webkit-search-results-button,
.aa-demo-1 .aa-input-search::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
  display: none
}

.aa-demo-1 .aa-input-search:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-color: #3a96cf
}

.aa-demo-1 .aa-input-container input[type=search]:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(58, 150, 207, 0.1) !important;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(58, 150, 207, 0.1) !important
}

.aa-demo-1 .aa-input-icon {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 16px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  fill: #e4e4e4;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 10
}

.aa-demo-1 .aa-hint {
  color: #e4e4e4
}

.aa-demo-1 .aa-dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid rgba(228, 228, 228, 0.6);
  border-top-width: 1px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(241, 241, 241, 0.35);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(241, 241, 241, 0.35);
  font-size: 11px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.aa-demo-1 .aa-suggestion {
  padding: 12px !important;
  border-bottom: 0 !important;
  font-size: 1.1rem !important;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(228, 228, 228, 0.6) !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: .2s;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center
}

.aa-demo-1 .aa-suggestion:hover,
.aa-demo-1 .aa-suggestion.aa-cursor {
  background-color: rgba(241, 241, 241, 0.35) !important
}

.aa-demo-1 .aa-suggestion>span:first-child {
  color: #333
}

.aa-demo-1 .aa-suggestion>span:last-child {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #a9a9a9
}

.aa-demo-1 .aa-suggestion>span:first-child em,
.aa-demo-1 .aa-suggestion>span:last-child em {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  background-color: rgba(58, 150, 207, 0.1);
  padding: 2px 0 2px 2px
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2 id=see-it-in-action>See it in action</h2>
  <link href="/doc/tutorials/search-ui/autocomplete/auto-complete.css" rel=stylesheet/>
  <div class=aa-demo-1>
    <div class=aa-input-container>
      <p>
        <input type=search id=aa-demo-1-input class=aa-input-search placeholder="Search for players or videos..." name=search autocomplete=off required=required/>
      </p>
      <svg id=icon-search class=aa-input-icon viewBox="654 -372 1664 1664">
                                            <path d="M1806,332c0-123.3-43.8-228.8-131.5-316.5C1586.8-72.2,1481.3-116,1358-116s-228.8,43.8-316.5,131.5 C953.8,103.2,910,208.7,910,332s43.8,228.8,131.5,316.5C1129.2,736.2,1234.7,780,1358,780s228.8-43.8,316.5-131.5 C1762.2,560.8,1806,455.3,1806,332z M2318,1164c0,34.7-12.7,64.7-38,90s-55.3,38-90,38c-36,0-66-12.7-90-38l-343-342 c-119.3,82.7-252.3,124-399,124c-95.3,0-186.5-18.5-273.5-55.5s-162-87-225-150s-113-138-150-225S654,427.3,654,332 s18.5-186.5,55.5-273.5s87-162,150-225s138-113,225-150S1262.7-372,1358-372s186.5,18.5,273.5,55.5s162,87,225,150s113,138,150,225 S2062,236.7,2062,332c0,146.7-41.3,279.7-124,399l343,343C2305.7,1098.7,2318,1128.7,2318,1164z"/>
                                        </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/algoliasearch/3/algoliasearch.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/autocomplete.js/0/autocomplete.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/doc/tutorials/4-search-ui/autocomplete/auto-complete.js"></script>
</section>
```

Comment: It works fine on a normal input, the problem is that I am using an algolia autocomplete service for this input, then it is not working anymore.

Comment: @Leff I've updated my answer to use the example provided on the Algolia documentation. It works exactly as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `autocomplete:opened` for detecting on focus. set `openOnFocus` is true 
and add `opened`.

**openOnFocus – If true, the dropdown menu will open when the input is focused. Defaults to false.**

```
.on('autocomplete:opened', function (e) {
    alert('opened on focus')
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var input = document.getElementsByClassName('search-input search-input-small-js form-control aa-input-search')[0];
  var test= document.getElementById("zxc");
     input.onfocus=function(){
     test.style.background="yellow";
     test.innerHTML="someone start searching";           
       }           
      




var client = algoliasearch('myKey', 'myValue');
var players = client.initIndex('players');
var videos = client.initIndex('videos');

var timeAgo = function(selector) {

    var templates = {
        prefix: "",
        suffix: " ago",
        seconds: "less than a minute",
        minute: "about a minute",
        minutes: "%d minutes",
        hour: "about an hour",
        hours: "about %d hours",
        day: "a day",
        days: "%d days",
        month: "about a month",
        months: "%d months",
        year: "about a year",
        years: "%d years"
    };
    var template = function (t, n) {
        return templates[t] && templates[t].replace(/%d/i, Math.abs(Math.round(n)));
    };

    var timer = function (time) {
        if (!time) return;
        time = time.replace(/\.\d+/, ""); // remove milliseconds
        time = time.replace(/-/, "/").replace(/-/, "/");
        time = time.replace(/T/, " ").replace(/Z/, " UTC");
        time = time.replace(/([\+\-]\d\d)\:?(\d\d)/, " $1$2"); // -04:00 -> -0400
        time = new Date(time * 1000 || time);

        var now = new Date();
        var seconds = ((now.getTime() - time) * .001) >> 0;
        var minutes = seconds / 60;
        var hours = minutes / 60;
        var days = hours / 24;
        var years = days / 365;

        return templates.prefix + (
        seconds < 45 && template('seconds', seconds) || seconds < 90 && template('minute', 1) || minutes < 45 && template('minutes', minutes) || minutes < 90 && template('hour', 1) || hours < 24 && template('hours', hours) || hours < 42 && template('day', 1) || days < 30 && template('days', days) || days < 45 && template('month', 1) || days < 365 && template('months', days / 30) || years < 1.5 && template('year', 1) || template('years', years)) + templates.suffix;
    };

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('timeago');
    for (var i in elements) {
        var $this = elements[i];
        if (typeof $this === 'object') {
            $this.innerHTML = timer($this.getAttribute('title') || $this.getAttribute('datetime'));
        }
    }
    // update time every minute
    setTimeout(timeAgo, 60000);
};

autocomplete('.search-input', {
    templates: {
        footer: '<div class="powered-by-algolia"><div class="pull-right"><img src="/imagecache/xs/Algolia_logo_bg-white.jpg" /></div></div>'
      }
    },
    [{
      source: autocomplete.sources.hits(players, { hitsPerPage: 5 }),
      displayKey: 'first_name',
      templates: {
        header: '<div class="aa-suggestions-category"><span>Players</span></div>',
        suggestion: function(suggestion) {
          var birthday = suggestion.birthday;
          var birthdayArray = birthday.split('/');
          var age = function (birthDay, birthMonth, birthYear) {
            var todayDate = new Date();
            var todayYear = todayDate.getFullYear();
            var todayMonth = todayDate.getMonth();
            var todayDay = todayDate.getDate();
            var age = todayYear - birthYear;

            if (todayMonth < birthMonth - 1){
              age--;
            }

            if (birthMonth - 1 == todayMonth && todayDay < birthDay){
              age--;
            }

            return age;
          }

          var old = age(birthdayArray[0], birthdayArray[1], birthdayArray[2]);

          return '<span>'
                + '<a href="/player/' + suggestion.id + '/' + suggestion.first_name.toLowerCase() + '-' + suggestion.last_name.toLowerCase() + '">'
                +   '<div class="media">'
                +     '<div class="media-left">'
                +       '<img class="media-object" src="/imagecache/small/' + suggestion.image_filename + '">'
                +     '</div>'
                +     '<div class="media-body">'
                +       '<p>' + suggestion._highlightResult.first_name.value + " " + suggestion._highlightResult.last_name.value + '<small> ' + old + ' years</small>' + '</p>'
                +       '<small> ' + suggestion.nationality + ' '+ suggestion.position + '</small>'
                +     '</div>'
                +   '</div>'
                + '</a>'
                +'</span>';
        }
      }
    },
    {
      source: autocomplete.sources.hits(videos, { hitsPerPage: 5 }),
      displayKey: 'title',
      templates: {
        header: '<div class="aa-suggestions-category"><span>Videos</span></div>',
        suggestion: function(suggestion) {
          timeAgo();
          return '<span>'
                +  '<a href="/player/video/' + suggestion.uid + '/' + suggestion.player_name.toLowerCase() + '-' + suggestion.player_surname.toLowerCase() + '">'
                +    '<div class="media">'
                +      '<img class="d-flex mr-3" src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/videos.football-talents.com/' + suggestion.video_id + '_1.jpg">'
                +      '<div class="media-body">'
                +        '<p>' + suggestion._highlightResult.title.value + ' <small class="timeago" title="' + suggestion.created_at + '">' + suggestion.created_at + '</small>' + '</p>'
                +        '<small> ' + suggestion._highlightResult.player_name.value + " " + suggestion._highlightResult.player_surname.value + '</small>'
                +      '</div>'
                +    '</div>'
                +  '</a>'
                +'</span>';
        }
      }
    }
]).on('autocomplete:updated', function(event, suggestion, dataset) {
  var timeagoTimeout;
  clearTimeout(timeagoTimeout);
  timeAgo();
  timeagoTimeout = setTimeout(timeAgo, 60000);
});
```

```css
.algolia-autocomplete {
  display: flex!important;
  flex: auto!important;
}
.aa-dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  top: -6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 6px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: $white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.aa-dropdown-menu:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 0;
  top: -7px;
  border-top: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  border-right: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  border-radius: 2px;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  left: 24px;
}

.aa-dropdown-menu .aa-suggestions {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.aa-dropdown-menu [class^="aa-dataset-"] {
  position: relative;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px;
  color: #3c3e42;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.aa-dropdown-menu * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.aa-suggestion {
  padding: 0 4px 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 38px;
  clear: both;
}
.aa-suggestion span {
  white-space: nowrap !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
}
.aa-suggestion.aa-cursor {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.aa-suggestion em {
  color: #00bcd4;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.aa-suggestion img {
  float: left;
  height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.aa-suggestion a {
  color: #3c3e42;
}

.aa-suggestions-category {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #3c3e42;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(102, 105, 105, 0.17);
}

.powered-by-algolia {
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(102, 105, 105, 0.17);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30px;
}

.aa-input-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative; }
.aa-input-search {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 12px 28px 12px 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none; }
.aa-input-search::-webkit-search-decoration, .aa-input-search::-webkit-search-cancel-button, .aa-input-search::-webkit-search-results-button, .aa-input-search::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
  display: none;
}
.media {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.media-body {
  p {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="zxc"></span><br />
<form action="/search" method="get">
       <div class="input-group">
         <span class="input-group-addon">
           <button type="submit" class="search-button">
             <i class="ion-ios-search-strong"></i>
           </button>
         </span>
         <input type="text" name="q" class="search-input search-input-small-js form-control aa-input-search" placeholder="Search for players and videos ..." aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
       </div>
     </form>
```

I added span over form just to show the response and I don't know if this code will affect other function but it could detects when input is focusing unless in IE 8 , for IE 8 you could use another workaround but for oninput .